# SO: tag name suggestion for Authentication, Authorization and Accounting?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-block-request, ambiguous-tags

The [`[aaa]` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aaa) <strike>is</strike> was used to mean two separate things:

- [Arrange Act Assert](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) (in unit testing)
- [Authentication, Authorization and Accounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAA_protocol) (in computer security)

For the former, [there is already a tag available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrange-act-assert), but for the latter there is none, and `[authentication-authorization-accounting]` is way over the 25 character length limit.

**Any suggestions to a short enough tag name?** Since I am not an expert of the field, I would rather not make suggestions myself.

Btw the existing posts which used to have the tag [aaa] in the security protocol sense are:

- [What is the most elegant and efficient way to provide AAA to web services using a WS gateway and LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273652/what-is-the-most-elegant-and-efficient-way-to-provide-aaa-to-web-services-using-a)
- [Know any AAA software as a service solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201805/know-any-aaa-software-as-a-service-solution)
- [rails - authentication, authorization and auditing confussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270815/rails-authentication-authorization-and-auditing-confussion)

---

#### Epilogue

I retagged the above posts with [`aaa-security-protocol`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aaa-security-protocol). I also searched through posts tagged `[authentication]` and `[authorization]`, to find any related to AAA, but there seems to be none.

To avoid future confusion, **please blacklist the `[aaa]` tag**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### aaa-security-protocol

From the name of [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAA_protocol).

Comment: @Péter Török: Fair enough.